# How do Let expressions work in AST?

Tags: haskell, abstract-syntax-tree, name-binding

Consider:

```
data Expr a
  = V a
  | Lit Integer
  | Let (Expr a) (Expr (Maybe a))
    deriving (Eq,Show)
```

The `Let` constructor enables me to bind an expression (first arg) in order to reference it in the second (`V Nothing` refers to it).

If I do something like

```
Let (Lit 3) $ Let (Lit 1) $ Var Nothing
```

which `Lit` does the `Var Nothing` refer to? Furthermore, I’d like to generalize that to
multiple bindings at once, and I have no idea how to do that. I followed some examples from the excellent Edward Kmett [bound](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bound) package, but now I’m both confused and lost.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm guessing slightly because I haven't seen this style of binding before, but I think the `Maybe` type is effectively being used to encode [*de Bruijn indices*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_index).

The basic idea there is that references to bound variables are stored as a number specifying the number of surrounding binders to go through to reach the relevant binder. So for example 0 would refer to the closest surrounding binder, 1 to the next closest, and so on.

I think what's happening here is that `Maybe` is being used to count the binders instead. So `Nothing` is equivalent to 0 and refers to the closest binder, and `Just Nothing` is equivalent to 1 and refers to the next closest, and so on.

So in your example, the `V Nothing` would refer to `Lit 1`, whereas `V (Just Nothing)` would refer to `Lit 3`.

Comment: Ok, but the `V (Just Nothing)` doesn’t type check, does it?

Comment: It should do, because the type parameter inside two `Let`s will be `Maybe (Maybe a)`.

Comment: This is almost certainly it. Reminds me a lot of how `bound` works.